# Symfony routing to external url with parameters creates extra /

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

This might be an easy one for PHP expert. I am fairly new to php and symfony hence couldn't find why this is happening. I have the below code which routes to an external url

```
$hostUrl = (APP_SSL ? "https" : "http")."://".$workspace->subdomain.".".APP_BASE_URL;

//redirect to workspace
return $this->redirect($hostUrl."?token=".$workspaceUser->apiToken."&user=".$workspaceUser->documentcode);
```

now the problem is when i try it in chrome or safari i get an extra slash before the params

http://test.testapp.localhost.test.com/?token=xxx&user=12345

how can i avoid this?

Comment: You can do `return $this->redirect(rtrim($hostUrl, '/')."?token=".$workspaceUser->apiToken."&user=".$workspaceUser->documentcode);`. But what is in `APP_BASE_URL` constant?

Comment: tried the rtrim but it doesnt work coz APP_BASE_URL is just testapp.localhost.test.com

Comment: There is no url changing in Symfony - https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/RedirectResponse.php#L88 - so maybe browser change it.